# Unable to test a trigger that post a Slack message via Apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, slack

I receive a

> ApplicationException: Error processing ChatPostMessageRequest

when I run this Apex test for my simple PoC of the [Apex SDK for Slack](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-slack-sdk).

```
@IsTest
private static void onNewAccount() {
    
    // Setup
    Slack.TestHarness.State state = new Slack.TestHarness().getNewSlackState();
    Slack.TestHarness.Team team = state.createTeam('any');
    Slack.TestHarness.Channel channel = state.createPrivateChannel('any');
    Slack.TestHarness.UserSession session = state.createUserSession();

    insert new Settings__c(txt_SlackTeam__c = team.getId(), txt_SlackChannel__c = channel.getId());

    
    // Exercise
    Test.startTest();
    insert new Account(...);
    Test.stopTest();


    // Verify
    System.assertEquals(1, session.getMessages().size());
}
```

This is what the code does: when a new record is inserted, the Trigger will delegate it to a Class that executes a Queueable to post a message to a predefined Slack channel. [All code can be found on Github](https://github.com/rsoesemann/salesforce-isv-cockpit/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/NotifySlackChannel_Test.cls).

```
public void execute() {
    if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
        execute(null);
    }
    else {
        System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
}


public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    Slack.App app = Slack.App.IsvCockpit.get();
    Slack.BotClient botClient = app.getBotClientForTeam(settings.txt_SlackTeam__c);
    
    Slack.ViewReference view = Slack.View.recordNotification.get();
    view.setParameter('header', 'ALERT: New ' + record.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getLabel() + ' has been created.');
    view.setParameter('recordId', record.Id);
    view.setParameter('recordLink', URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + record.Id);

    Slack.ChatPostMessageRequest request = new Slack.ChatPostMessageRequest.builder()
                                                            .channel(settings.txt_SlackChannel__c)
                                                            .viewReference(view)
                                                            .build();

    Slack.ChatPostMessageResponse response = botclient.chatPostMessage(request);
    if(!response.isOk()) {
        throw new ApplicationException('' +response);
    }
}
```

**Note:** When I remove `Test.startTest/stopTest` my test fails with

> System.CalloutException: Callout from triggers are currently not
> supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a product limitation at this point. The Test harness for Slack SDK does not support cases when Slack specific code gets called in asynchronous context.

The product team has a feature request for it which we can only hope they get to it before GA.

For now I can suggest simply using the Stub API to mock out the methods to return a mock response.

Comment: How would you do that Mohit? How can I mock/stub the response to Slack SDK callouts which I don't see because they are encapsulated behind the SDK.

Comment: Ah sorry for not being so clear! Can you not create a method and class (kind of wrapped class) and have the logic in there and then just mock those classes and method.

Comment: I will see if I find some time to put together some code.